# Performing normalization of panda column grouped by values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, normalization

I want to do `z-score` normalization as described here [(link)](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-normalization-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn-7c1cc6ed6475) which is basically given by `x_normalized = (x- x_mean)/x_std`. I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
  
country = ['US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'Canada', 'Canada', "Mexico"]
rating =  [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 1] 

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(country,rating)),
               columns =['country', 'rating'])
```

which is

```
    country     rating
0   US            0
1   US            2
2   US            1
3   UK            4
4   UK            3
5   Canada        1
6   Canada        0
7   Mexico        1
```

Now I want to perform z-score normalization of the `rating` column grouped by for each different values of `country` column. That is for value `US` performing normalization of values `0, 2, 1`, for `UK` values `4, 3` and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `transform`:

```
>>> df.groupby("country")["rating"].transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean())/x.std())
0   -1.000000
1    1.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.707107
4   -0.707107
5    0.707107
6   -0.707107
7         NaN
Name: rating, dtype: float64
```

Comment: For `Mexico`, shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: @hi15 - There's only one observation. Standard deviation is 0. Dividing by 0 is causing the NaN